# Seeing how column was calculated in ArcGIS Pro from Calculate Field in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator

I have a project in ArcGIS Pro from a colleague. I know they calculated a column in an attribute table from other columns in the same attribute table.

Is there a way to see what calculation they used to get the result in the column?

They used Calculate Field in ArcGIS Pro 2.8.0

Comment: If the geoprocessing action was logged (and the log is available/not deleted), maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Open the History pane by clicking the Analysis ribbon > History button in the Geoprocessing group. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/geoprocessing-history.htm

If you do not see the Calculate Field history there, then unfortunately there is no way to see what calculation was done.